# Jest mocking TypeScript class "No overload expects 1 type arguments"

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a TypeScript class with Jest and I'm obviously doing something because receive the following error:

```
error TS2743: No overload expects 1 type arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 0 or 2 type arguments.
```

This is my code:

Foo.ts

```
export default class Foo {
  bar(): number {
    return Math.random()
  }
}
```

Foo.test.ts

```
import Foo from './Foo'

describe('Foo', () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    const MockFoo = jest.fn<Foo>(() => ({
      bar: jest.fn(() => {
        return 123
      }),
    }))
  })
})
```

The full error:

```
TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
src/Foo.test.ts:6:29 - error TS2743: No overload expects 1 type arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 0 or 2 type arguments.

6     const MockFoo = jest.fn<Foo>(() => ({
                              ~~~
```

**UPDATE**

If it is of any relevance, this is my Jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['**/src/**/*.test.(ts)'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Jest has the following signature for jest.fn:

```js
/**
 * Creates a mock function. Optionally takes a mock implementation.
 */
function fn<T, Y extends any[]>(implementation?: (...args: Y) => T): Mock<T, Y>;
```

So you need to specify the array of types for the args, in your particular case you could just pass an empty array as there are no args in your implementation function.

```js
const MockFoo = jest.fn<Foo, []>(() => ({
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest)'s `mocked()` function:

This is all type safe and compiles without warnings in TypeScript:

```
import Foo from './Foo'
import {mocked} from 'ts-jest/utils'

function argIsFoo(foo : Foo) {
    ; // do nothing
}

describe('Foo', () => {
    it("should pass", () => {
        const mockFoo = mocked({
            bar: jest.fn(() => {
                return 123
            })
        });

        // mockFoo is compatible with Foo class
        argIsFoo(mockFoo);

        // method has the right type
        expect(mockFoo.bar()).toEqual(123);

        // can use the mock in expectations
        expect(mockFoo.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();

        // is type safe access method as a mock
        expect(mockFoo.bar.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

---

If you only want to mock out some of Foo's methods, then in `mocked()` you need to cast your *mock object* with `as unknown as Foo`:

```
import {mocked} from 'ts-jest/utils'

class Foo {
    bar(): number {
        return Math.random();
    }
    dontMockMe(): string {
        return "buzz";
    }
}

function argIsFoo(foo : Foo) {
    ; // do nothing
}

describe('Foo', () => {
    it("should pass", () => {
        const mockFoo = mocked({
            bar: jest.fn(() => {
                return 123
            })
        } as unknown as Foo);

        // mockFoo is compatible with Foo class
        argIsFoo(mockFoo);

        // method has the right type
        expect(mockFoo.bar()).toEqual(123);

        // can use the mock in expectations
        expect(mockFoo.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();

        // is type safe access method as a mock
        expect(mockFoo.bar.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it's possible to have the TypeScript compiler ignore errors like this by turning off diagnostics [1].

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      diagnostics: false
    }
  }
};
```

However, it's currently unclear to me what other implications this might have.

[1] https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/diagnostics#enabling-diagnostics-for-test-files-only

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Chesley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55301124/110464) the signature of `fn` is responsible for the error. That is, the signature that you get when you use the jest types from `@types/jest`!

If instead you import jest as explained in TypeScript usage section of [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#typescript-usage) via

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
```

, the signature of `fn` works the way you intended to use it, as `@jest/globals` has the following signature:

```
fn<T extends FunctionLike = UnknownFunction>(implementation?: T): Mock<T>
```