# How to strongly type jest mocks

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-typings, ts-jest

I would like to strongly type my jest mocks. To a certain extent, I can make it work but when a class has private properties I'm stuck.

An additional question, when I use mocks (the way I currently do) the return type is of the original type but when I have to access any method added by Jest I have to typecast it so `jest.Mock` to access a method. Is there a better way to do this? I've tried to work with `jest.Mock`, `jest.Mocked`, `jest.MockInstance`.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

```js
class MyTest {
    constructor(private readonly msg: string) {}

    public foo(): string {
        return this.msg;
    }
}

const myTestMock: jest.Mock<MyTest, [string]> = jest.fn<MyTest, [string]>(() => ({
    msg: 'private',
    foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('aaa'),
}));
// Results in error:
// Type '{ msg: string; foo: Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'MyTest'.
// Property 'msg' is private in type 'MyTest' but not in type '{ msg: string; foo: Mock<any, any>; }'

const myTestMockInstance: MyTest = new myTestMock('a');
console.log(myTestMockInstance.foo()); // --> aaa

// Accessing jest mock methods:
(<jest.Mock>myTestMockInstance).mockClear(); // <-- can this be done without type casting
```

Dirty workaround:

```js
const myTestMock: jest.Mock<MyTest, [string]> = jest.fn<MyTest, [string]>(
    // Cast to any to satisfy TS
    (): any => ({
        msg: 'private',
        foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('aaa'),
    })
);
```

Comment: What's the problem with private properties? IMO you should only mock (and test) the public interface. Have you had a look at this article? https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/strongly-typed-mock-with-typescript-and-jest

Comment: @KimKern The problem is that typescript throws an error because the mock does not contain the private property so my mock does not match the type I'm trying to mock.

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting article although I consider it a work around it might be the best option for now. I would expect jest to already have a way of doing it instead of creating your own alias.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely only a work around. :/ I'm using it and I also had problems with this approach. But since jest is migrating to typescript for the next major release I hope this will get better. Also see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7832

Answer (score 8):

There is a library that can help you with strongly typed mocks in Typescript with Jest: [jest-mock-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-extended)

I'm not sure you should be accessing private properties of your mock. As Kim Kern says, you should only be interested in the public interface of the dependency of the unit under test.

jest-mock-extended contains a `mock()` method which returns a `MockProxy` which allows you to access `.mockReturnValue()` etc.

```js
import { mock } from "jest-mock-extended";

interface WidgetService {
  listMyWidgets(): { id: string }[];
};

const mockedService = mock<WidgetService>();
mockedService.listMyWidgets.mockReturnValue([{ id: 'widget-1' }]);
```

Comment: Adding `jest-mock-extended` module did the job excellently

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a helper which makes types: look [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/2ab1e447fab43730f75a92a2b87cde065cc56c9d/website/docs/guides/test-helpers.md)

2. usually you should test public interface, not an implementation. Instead of testing private methods you could extract that logic to a public interface (maybe to another class that provides the interface)

Comment: A worked example with ts-jest is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63074930/1402988

Comment: Note that ts-jest's mocking function has been incorporated into jest as of ts-jest 28.x https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/6d87eeab86a4da040f5a64d8f06c4495cb03b908/website/versioned_docs/version-27.1/guides/test-helpers.md

Answer (score -1):

You can use `jest.fn()` to mock instantiating the class object and omit specifying the type on the variable and let Typescript infer it.

`myTestMockInstance` will not have the type of `MyTest` because you are mocking it.

```js
class MyTest {
   constructor(private readonly msg: string) {}

   public foo(): string {
      return this.msg
   }
}

const myTestMock = jest.fn((msg: string) => ({
   msg,
   foo() {
      return this.msg
   }
}))

const myTestMockInstance = new myTestMock('a')
console.log(myTestMockInstance.foo()) // --> a
```